# Magento custom theme to default theme redirection issue

Tags: default, theme-fallback

First of all I am explaining settings and scenario of my magento.

1. I have add a link ‘go to form’ on product view page and call my custom controller on click.
2. I add following code in my controller.

   ```
   public function indexAction()
   {
     $this->loadLayout();
     $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                 'Mage_Core_Block_Template',
                  mycompany.mylink,
                  array(
                  'template' => mycompany/mylinkform.phtml'
                   )
            ) ->setData('varNameOne', 1')
              ->setData('varNameTwo', 2');

     $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
     $this->_initLayoutMessages('core/session');
     $this->renderLayout();
   }
   ```
3. On frontend, theme is look like custom theme. If I start template path I can see path like: frontend/default/theme name/..
4. But on backend theme name is set as ‘Default’.

Now, issue is: ‘go to form’ is open in custom theme which has a path like frontend/default/theme name/template/....    But when I click on this link, my form is open in default theme which has a path like frontend/default/default/template/…

So why this is happening? When I click on link, my form must open in custom theme but I will redirected to default theme and open over there.

I have add .phtml file of form in both the theme.

Please help me on this.

This is a back end theme setting.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `mycompany/mylinkform.phtml` is not present or misconfigured in your custom theme.

In order to use `mycompany/mylinkform.phtml` from your custom theme, you need to ensure two things.

1. In the Admin side, you need to set current theme as your custom theme. For the sake of illustration, I am calling theme name as `custom_theme`
2. Then you need to put your phtml template at `app\design\frontend\default\custom_theme/mycompany/mylinkform.phtml`.

**Note :-** Here I assume, package is `default`.

So make sure that file does exist in your custom theme. Clear all cache and then try again.

Comment: Well it is not good to say client for change theme name from default to custom theme name in backend. Other thing,I already install my file in custom  theme but then also it is redirected to default theme.

Comment: show your backend theme configuration. We cant help you without seeing that. Update your question with a screenshot of admin theme configuration. As per your comment, Magento is not going to use your custom theme. Because your theme is set to `default`. So magento will look in default theme directory only.

Comment: Please have look on screenshot.

Comment: @Krupali As I guess, your package name is `default` and you didnt set any theme in backend. Put your custom theme at `default` field will solve every problem

Comment: Sorry but can you please elaborate this.How and where set ? In File structure at frontend/defalut/custom_theme  or at back end ?

Comment: @Krupali in backend. In your screenshot, the last field is labeled as `Default`. You need to set your custom theme name there. The normal way is put your custom theme name in every field which comes under `Theme` field set.If possible do that. Otherwise change default field